# List all Tests Found by Nosetest

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, nosetests

I use `nosetests` to run my unittests and it works well. I want to get a list of all the tests `nostests` finds without actually running them. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Version 0.11.1 is currently available.  You can get a list of tests without running them as follows:

```
nosetests -v --collect-only
```

Comment: See [`-vv`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3448487/232794) as a better option than `-v`.

Comment: `nosetests -v --collect-only | grep 'some-string'` is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: @EyalLevin I ran into the same thing. The output goes to stderr, so you need to do `nosetests -v --collect-only 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'some-string'`

Answer (score 18):

I recommend using:

```
nosetests -vv --collect-only
```

While the `-vv` option is not described in `man nosetests`, ["An Extended Introduction to the nose Unit Testing Framework"](http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/nose-intro.html) states that:

> Using the -vv flag gives you verbose output from nose's test discovery algorithm. This will tell you whether or not nose is even looking in the right place(s) to find your tests.

The `-vv` option can save time when trying to determine why nosetests is only finding some of your tests. (In my case, it was because nosetests skipped certain tests because the `.py` scripts were executable.)

Bottom line is that the `-vv` option is incredibly handy, and I almost always use it instead of the `-v` option.

Answer (score 3):

There will be soon: a new `--collect` switch that produces this behavior was demoed at PyCon last week. It should be on the trunk "soon" and will be in the 0.11 release.

The https://groups.google.com/g/nose-users list is a great resource for nose questions.