# Display list of all tests in a Django project

Tags: django, testing, django-testing

Is there an easy way to get a list of all tests in a Django project without running the tests themselves? I was hoping for something like `./manage.py test --list`.

Comment: besides `grep -R "^\w*def test_.*\(.*\)\:$" --include "*.py"`?

Comment: Running that on OS X 10.8.3 returned `grep: warning: recursive search of stdin` and the process hung indefinitely without returning any results. Modifying the command to `grep -R "def test_" --include "*.py" .` worked for me. Thanks for the clever solution.

Comment: I'm not using `nose`, so this grep-based approach worked great for me!

Comment: Unfortunately the `grep` method doesn't work when test functions are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my opinion, the more correct way is to use the actual tool for running tests. E.g. in case of [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
./manage.py test <app> --verbosity 2 --collect-only
```

FYI, [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/) also has `--collectonly` option to print tests instead of executing.

Also see:

- [List all Tests Found by Nosetest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712020/list-all-tests-found-by-nosetest)

Comment: I don't see `nose` options when running either `manage.py --help` or `mange.py test --help`, unfortunately. It's strange because I can see my tests are definitely being run via `nose`. I tried reinstalling `django-nose` but no luck. It must be something on my end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please try to move `django_nose` to the end of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I now see the `nose` command-line options and your original answer to the question works as well.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I'm running the command with Docker, but just ignore the Docker command and get the command inside the quotes.

django.test | unittest

```bash
sudo docker compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py test --verbosity 2 --force-color"
```

```bash
(venv) ➜  recipe-app-api git:(main) ✗ sudo docker compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py test --verbosity 2 --force-color"
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container recipe-app-api-db-1  Running                                                                                                         0.0s
Skipping setup of unused database(s): default.
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
test_add_numbers (app.tests.CalcTests)
Test adding number together. ... ok
test_subtract_numbers (app.tests.CalcTests)
Test subtracting numbers. ... ok
test_wait_for_db_delay (core.tests.test_commands.CommandTests)
Test waiting for database when  getting OperationalError. ... Waiting for database...
Database unvailable, waiting 1 second...
Database unvailable, waiting 1 second...
Database unvailable, waiting 1 second...
Database unvailable, waiting 1 second...
Database unvailable, waiting 1 second...
Database available!
ok
test_wait_for_db_ready (core.tests.test_commands.CommandTests)
Test waiting for database if database ready. ... Waiting for database...
Database available!
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.007s

OK
```

You can pass the verbosity or just -v parameter.
The -v parameter has more 4 options to display the test in the screen.

For more information regarding the options:

```bash
usage: manage.py test [-h] [--noinput] [--failfast] [--testrunner TESTRUNNER] [-t TOP_LEVEL] [-p PATTERN] [--keepdb] [-r] [--debug-mode] [-d]
                      [--parallel [N]] [--tag TAGS] [--exclude-tag EXCLUDE_TAGS] [--pdb] [-b] [--no-faulthandler] [--timing] [-k TEST_NAME_PATTERNS]
                      [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color] [--force-color]
                      [test_label ...]
```

Comment: The question specifies that the tests should only be counted (not run). The output from your example indicates the tests are being run, making this answer unsuitable.